# Top Questions of the Week #24

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 24 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about, it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Comment: This week was a tie between "why are we still using CPUs instead of GPUs" and "Why did defragging increase disk space?". We will be writing about defragmentation for Monday; expect a post about GPUs in the future!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's something that you don't see every other day

- [Why did defragmenting C drive increase my free disk space by 10 GB?](https://superuser.com/questions/307808/why-did-defragmenting-c-drive-increase-disk-space-by-10gb)

Comment: Great one, I remember the first time I ever defragged and wondered why I had such a big boost too.

Comment: @Sathya what happened to Not Doc's account? 19 up votes and a checkmark, and he still only has 1 rep? Some note on his account that it's being suspended for a full year to "cool down"? I went looking at his comments and didn't see any that seemed heated, unless they've already been deleted.

Comment: @Spiff The comments have been cleaned up.

Answer (score 9):

- [Why are we still using CPUs instead of GPUs?](https://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus)

With the recently influx of people using GPU's for work with Folding@home (or any other such things), as well as Bitcoin mining, it's definitely something that has been noticeable recently.

Unfortunately I have a poor man's GPU, so I could not run any tests on it to write a post on it.

Comment: That last part is something we can fix ;-) Are you going to mine bitcoins as well if we sponsor a GPU?

Comment: @Ivo Unfortunately no, I've got no intention of doing so. However, after taking a more serious look at my GPU, I think I could test it using Folding@home stuff. I'm testing it as we speak to see what I can manage :)

Comment: @Ivo Flipse, after the latest few difficulty changes, mining bitcoins got a **lot** less profitable (it doubled over the past month).  [Click me for some graphs.](http://bitcoin.sipa.be/)

Answer (score 0):

That one's interesting as well, given that it is well asked and the answers reveal something which not everybody knows. One could write about administrative shares in more detail in the blog then.

> ### [Security Concern with my Windows 7 Box at Work](https://superuser.com/questions/311061/security-concern-with-my-windows-7-box-at-work)
>
> The group I'm in recently got new computers at work. They gave me a new computer and hooked up my old computer to the network for a week so I could take my time transferring necessary files/configs etc. The Support Guy said, "Just go to 'run' and type in \PCNAME\c$. So I did and, low and behold, there's my old C: drive. I thought to myself, "What a huge security issue. I'll just transfer everything quickly and then 'un-share' it." [...]

Comment: But I guess I'll just nominate that for next week :P

Comment: Next week is probably a better idea, yes.